# How do I kill these weeds in my lawn?

Tags: lawn, fall-gardening, weeds

I am not able to kill these weeds in my garden.

*Click on any image for full size*

[image: wild]

[image: wild2]

[image: wild3]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you have clover and thyme and grass all co existing in the same area.  This mix is actually recommended for a low maintenance area.

I do not recommend Round up to solve this.  You would have to apply it over the whole area and really soak it in then you would not be able to do replanting for at least a week or more.

It is just as effective to dig up the area with a turf spade and re sod. You would be doing that anyway if you apply Roundup.  Or, if you wait till fall you can over seed with grass.

If that is thyme in the photos then the question is how can it compete with grass?  Normally grass has no problems out growing it.  Thyme thrives on dry soils with lots of sun.  Consider applying compost or other organic matter to help retain moisture.  This will prevent the thyme from reappearing from any seeds.

Comment: Would you kill the thyme first then apply compost?

Comment: @Danger14 The grass, clover and thyme is all mixed together.  You cannot kill one of them.  Either remove them all by digging out or Roundup or learn to love them together.